# send_mail how to get rid of DNS in "From" field?

Tags: php, email, dns, sendmail, send

Made a simple script with sendmail but every time I send a message I see my DNS in From field instead of what I am trying to put in mail headers. I have no idea how to get rid of that, why it is happening? Here is a function. Maybe someone could help?

```
function send_mail($to,$subj,$text)
{
    $mail_headers = <<<END
From: "MyName"<support@myname.com>
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
END;
    mail($to,$subj,$text,$mail_headers);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

By DNS I mean my hosting mailing DNS so instead of my name inside FROM I get something like `MyName support@myname.com@server03.abstractdns.com` or `MyName support@myname.com@server03.abstractdns.com`

Comment: What do you mean by "my DNS"? What kind of address are you trying to specify as the "from" address? Is the domain of the address being handled by that server?

Comment: @pekka I mean I get my hosting mail dns like server03.abstractdns.com and in the form I see smth like MyName support@myname.com@server03.abstractdns.com

Comment: Without quotes I get MyName support@myname.com via server03.abstractdns.com

Comment: @Alex Sounds like this may be down to the way that your server's sendmail program is configured, and if you are on shared hosting there may not be much that you can do about this. Try [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) instead - this will allow you to bypass the `mail()` function and/or use your own sendmail program.

Comment: You can try `mail($to,$subj,$text,$mail_headers, "-f support@myname.com");` - some shared hosting environments need the fifth parameter

Comment: @DaveRandom Please summarize it and I will accept it as the answer. Unfortunately nothing else helped, switching to swiftmail.